# Using phpMyAdmin import CSV feature with Apostrophes

Tags: csv, phpmyadmin

I am looking at importing several hundred rows from a CSV file but any row that contains an Apostrophe gets cut off after the Apostrophe. Is there a way to have phpMyAdmin ignore this? I have been searching with no answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by exporting as OpenDocument spreadsheet in Excel and then importing.